# Lua Scripting Guess-The-Logo game DevProduct Skip

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently making a Roblox game that allows the user to guess the logo in front of them and the logo would turn CanCollide off for them to go through, and I want to connect a DevProduct so whenever someone clicks on the skip(ProximityPrompt(e)), the DevProduct will show up for the player to purchased, and when purchased, the door will turn CanCollide off for 7 seconds. The map has different starting doors for different category, and each door has more doors as the user guesses each door in that category correct.

My problem right now is that my script is only working on one door, and I am wondering how I can get it to work on all doors(note that each door has a different name.)

This is my script as of now

--in each door's script

```
script.Parent.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function()

    local marketPlaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
    marketPlaceService:PromptProductPurchase(game.Players.LocalPlayer, 1550501306)

end)



local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.PlayerAdded:Wait()

local productId = 1550501306


script.Parent.ProximityPrompt.Triggered:Connect(function()

local MarketplaceService = game:GetService("MarketplaceService")
MarketplaceService:PromptProductPurchase(player, productId)

end)

MarketplaceService.ProcessReceipt = function(receiptInfo)

    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerByUserId(receiptInfo.PlayerId)

    if receiptInfo.ProductId == 1550501306 then

    workspace.###.CanCollide = false
    workspace.SkipStageSound:Play()

    wait(7)

    workspace.###.CanCollide = true
    workspace.SkipStageSound:Stop()

    return Enum.ProductPurchaseDecision.PurchaseGranted

end
end`
```

With ### being the door's name.

I have this script in all doors/logos, but only the first one I put works.

What am I missing?